# Using non numeric values with jQuery slider widget

Tags: jquery, select, slider

Hi I am using jQuery slider to take peoples opinion in a questionnaire. The person can select a value of 1 to 10 on the slider or if they don't know they select 'dont know'. The problem I am having is I cant seem to get the slider to work out that the numbers should go 1-10 and then don't know being the first value if nothing is selected. If I use the code below the slider just doesn't move at all. It is also bound to a select box and controls it too.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var select = $( "#enjoyusingdevice" );
    var slider = $( "<div id='slider'></div>" ).insertAfter( select ).slider({
        min: dontknow,
        max: 10,
        range: "min",
        value: select[ 0 ].selectedIndex + 1,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            select[ 0 ].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
        }
    });
    $( "#enjoyusingdevice" ).change(function() {
        slider.slider( "value", this.selectedIndex + 1 );
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think you are running in a loop, setting the slider changes the select, that changes the slider...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values have to be numeric. Also, your `dontknow` is not wrapped in quotes, so it is actually looking for a variable named `dontknow`, which I'm guessing doesn't exist, so `min` is actually being set to `undefined`.

As a workaround you could have your slider going from values 1-10, with a separate checkbox for 'I don't know'. When users tick this checkbox the slider would be disabled.

Comment: I have seen it used with text values before on other websites, e.g for months of the year, is it just that the values cannot be mixed ?.

Comment: Months of the year would most likely have been value `0-11` with a array of localised months names for lookup.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will see if I can work it another way.